# fopen() in read-only mode and its buffer

Tags: c, io, stream, buffer

Consider the following, albeit very messy, code in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buf[3]; //a new, small buffer
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r"); //our test file, with the contents "123abc"
    setvbuf(fp, buf, _IOFBF, 2); //we assign our small buffer as fp's buffer \
                                 //in fully buffered mode
    char character = fgetc(fp); // get the first character...
    character = fgetc(fp);      // and the next...
    character = fgetc(fp);      // and the next... (third character, '3')
    buf[2] = '\0'; //add a terminating line for display
    fputs(buf, stderr); //write our buffer to stderr, should show up immediately
}
```

Compiling and running the code will print '3a' as the contents of our self-designated buffer, buf. My question is: **how does this buffer get filled?** Does a call to fgetc() mean several calls until the buffer is full and then stops (we only made three calls to fgetc, which should not include the present 'a')? The first buffer was "12", so does this mean when another fgetc() call is made and the pointer references something outside of the scope of the buffer, is the buffer purged and then filled with the next block of data, or simply overwritten? I understand buffer sizes are platform dependent so I'm more concerned with how, in general, an fopen()ed stream in a read mode pulls characters into it's buffer.

Comment: "Is the buffer purged and then filled with the next block of data, or simply overwritten" -- I'm not sure what the difference would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buffer, and exactly how and when it is filled, is an implementation detail inside the stdio package. But the way it is likely to be implemented is that **fgetc** gets one character from the buffer, if there are characters available in the buffer. If the buffer is empty, it fills it by reading (in your case) two more characters from the file.

So your first **fgetc** will read **12** from the file and put it in the buffer, and then return **'1'**. Your second **fgetc** will not read from the file, since a character is available in the buffer, and return **'2'**. Your third **fgetc** will find that the buffer is empty, so it will read **3a** from the file and put it in the buffer, and then return **'3'**. Therefore, when you print the content of the buffer, it will be **3a**.

Note that there are two levels of "reading" happening here. First you have your **fgetc** calls, and then, below that level, code inside the stdio packade which is reading from the file. If we assume this is on a Unix or Linux system, the second type of reading is done using the system call **read(2)**.

The lower-level reading fills the entire buffer at once, so you don't need as many  calls to **read** as  calls to **fgetc**. (Which is the entire point of having the buffer.)

Comment: Very succinct, thanks! What about in the circumstance where ungetc() might 'put back' a character from a previous 'block' or buffer section? Does that mean the previous block is read into the buffer again? e.g. would a call to ungetc() after the third call in the example above make read() pull in the "12" again into the stream's buffer and set the pointer location back to the "2"?

Comment: @RJS: I don't think **ungetc** will ever read from the file. It doesn't rewind the input stream, but puts characters in the input to be read later, so my guess is that it has a separate buffer for characters that were pushed back. Or a single variable, since the C standard only guarantees that it will work with a single character.

Comment: A quick look at some source code for one implementation (Apple's) seems to confirm this. If they can just move the current pointer in the input buffer backwards, they do so, but otherwise they have a separate ungetc buffer. (http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/stdio.subproj/ungetc.c)

Comment: Right, a bit like the K&R's implementation of `ungetc`. As a final related question, if the buffer is 'unbuffered' and a call to `fgetc` is performed, where does fgetc get it's data from? Immediately from the return of `read` meaning it could be a slower variant of the chunk-read default? From what you're saying I wouldn't assume that fgetc would ever read from the file, as it were.

Comment: Without having checked any source code or standards document: If the input stream is unbuffered, there is no buffer, so a **read(2)** call with size 1 is used to get a single character, and that character is returned by fgetc.